# Puedo crear en una clase un array con sus metodos y despues utilizar los metodos y el array en el main?

Tags: java

¿Puedo crear en una clase un array con sus metodos y despues utilizar los métodos y el array en el main?

Como hago para utilizar el método ordenarEdad y ordenarNombre con el array en el main para probar que funcionan bien los métodos..?
He investigado pero o no me entero o no encuentro solución..

```
package Ejecicio01;
public class Clases {

    String alumnos[]={"alex","laura","juan","paula","ruben"};
    int edad[]={15,13,20,18,19};
    
 
      
        public int[] ordenarEdad(int temp){ 
            for(int i=0; i<(edad.length-1);i++){
                for (int j=0; j<(edad.length-1);j++){
                    if(edad[j]>edad[j+1]){
                        temp=edad[j];
                        edad[j]=edad[j+1];
                        edad[j+1]=temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        return edad;
    }


     public String[] ordenarNombre(String ord){
        for(int i=1; i<=alumnos.length; i++) {  
            for(int j=0; j<alumnos.length-i; j++) { 
                if( alumnos[j].compareTo(alumnos[j+1])>0 ) { 
                    ord = alumnos[j]; 
                    alumnos[j]  = alumnos[j+1]; 
                    alumnos[j+1]= ord;        
                }
            }
        }
        return alumnos;
    }
   

**He probado a hacer esto pero no esta bien..**
```

package Ejercicio01;
public class Principal {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Clases a = new Clases();
String[] alumnos=a.alumnos;
int[]edad= a.edad;


for(int j=0;j<edad.length;j++){
   System.out.println(a.ordenarEdad(j));

}

    
}
```

}

Comment: `Clases clases = new Clases(); clases.ordenarEdad(0);`

Comment: Eso hice pero al querer imprimirlo me aparece esto..                                 
run-single:
[I@2f92e0f4
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Porque estás intentando imprimir un arreglo. Para que se te muestren los elementos en la consola usa `Arrays.toString(arr)` para convertir un arreglo a `String`.

Comment: Pero el nombre y la edad, ¿están relacionados o no? Si los ordenas por separado no se pierde la relación. No es mejor crear una clase Alumno que contenga los datos nombre y edad o el ejercicio te pide dos arrays separados. ?

Comment: El ejercicio me pide crear una matriz de 10 personas que conste de nombre y edad

Comment: Y después crear 2 métodos que ordenen por nombre y edad